# format shell output using array of args on jenkins-pipeline

Tags: arrays, json, shell, arguments, jenkins-pipeline

I'm a beginner with shell scripting and i have some issues while a jenkins job parametrized.
I'm using an array of args as input for a shell script divided into four args ($1 $2 $3 $4) and i used $params in Jenkinsfile as shown below :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
        stage('parse') {              
            steps {
                script{
                   sh "./test.sh ${params}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the content of shell script test.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$(echo -n $1 | jq -cRs 'split(",")') >file.json
echo $1
echo $a
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4
```

the main objective is to populate a json file with values of four elements (apis,name,version and status)
here is the jenkins output

```
+ ./test.sh [apis:dev,qa,prod, name:CC, version:g3, status:true]
[apis:dev,qa,prod,
["[apis:dev","qa","prod",""]
name:CC,
version:g3,
status:true]
```

my question is how format the output and eliminate characters `[`and `,` to obtain a clean result like `apis:"dev","qa","prod"` ?

Comment: What is the goal of this actions? Do you want to parse json using jq. Than you should pay attention to quotes `./test.sh '[apis:dev,qa,prod, name:CC, version:g3, status:true]'`. If you need working jenkins job, use `readJSON`/`writeJSON` steps instead of shell.

Comment: I want to write params to a json file with shell , i can't use readJSON /writeJSON because after i will use this script in ansible. And if there is any solution instead of shell please tell me.